# How to send HTTPS GET request using NODEMCU

Tags: https, arduino, wifi, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

How do you send a HTTPS - GET/POST request using Nodemcu - Arduino code.

I've ben searching days for a working example that sends a GET request using HTTPS protocol to a website and all examples that I've found were unsuccessful.

I hope it will help others too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here is the link that helped me](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/4826)

To make the examples work with the HTTPS protocol you would have to use the `WiFiClientSecure` library and call the `client.setInsecure()` function of the `WiFiClientSecure`'s object you have.

Here is a fully working code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "WIFI_SSID";
const char* password = "WIFI_PASS";

const char* host = "DOMAIN_NAME"; // only google.com not https://google.com

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  const int httpPort = 443; // 80 is for HTTP / 443 is for HTTPS!
  
  client.setInsecure(); // this is the magical line that makes everything work
  
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) { //works!
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  // We now create a URI for the request
  String url = "/arduino.php";
  url += "?data=";
  url += "aaaa";


  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);

  // This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
}
```

Comment: The authoritative resource is the official example at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/BearSSL_Validation/BearSSL_Validation.ino Take a look at the various `fetchXYZ` functions to understand the differences. Using `setInsecure()` should be your last resort IMO.